# Linear scaling between 2 font sizes using calc and vw

Tags: css, math, calc, viewport-units

Is it possible to use some combination of `calc()` and `vw` units to scale linearly between 2 different font sizes?

Example: I'm giving a web page design with the following font sizes:

`<h1>` is font-size: 18px @ 360px

`<h1>` is font-size: 32px @ 1024px

If I wish the `font-size` to scale up along with the browser width using `vw` units, the math is pretty simple (SCSS syntax):

`font-size: 18/360*100vw;` = `font-size: 5vw;`

So based on a font size of 18px @ 360px, you would use `5vw`. However, by the time the browser gets up to 1024px:

`1024*0.05 = 51.2px` which is how big the `<h1>` will be at 1024px which is far higher than the designed `32px`. The opposite problem will occur if I set the font-size to use 32px as the base: `font-size: 32/1024*100vw;` = `font-size: 3.125vw`. Now the font will be too small @360px;

So the question again, is it possible to linearly scale a `font-size` between 2 font-sizes at 2 different breakpoints? Is it possible to use some sort of combination or `vw` units and `calc` to achieve this. I've tried to work out the equation for such a thing but I'm not sure if it is possible.

I've been thinking about trying to something like:

`font-size: calc(18/360*100vw * 1.01vw);` or something along those lines but apparently that type of syntax is not accessible for `calc()`.

Note: I'm not looking for a simple media query solution where I simply increase the font size @1024px. I'm looking for a way to linearly scale it smoothly between all resolutions.

Comment: Have you seen my answer ? I believe it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An aproximate solution (I have not taken into account the fractions) would be

```
font-size: calc(2vw + 12px);
```

You need to solve the system of equations for the 2 points, and find the equation of the result

The first equation is , for a viewport of 360, a font size of 18. thus,

```
a * 3.6 + b = 18
```

Where a is the part of the vw units and b the px part

the second equation is

```
a * 10.24 + b = 32
```

Let's go to [webmath](http://www.webmath.com/solver2.html) and enter

[image]

The result given is

[image]

So your exact answer would be

```
font-size: calc (2.11vw + 10.41px);
```

Comment: That is a pretty close approximation. Thank you. I wonder how you do this a bit more precisely also using other font sizes. How did you find that magic "12px" value? Just trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try scaling whith media query:

```
.text {
    font-size: 5vw;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .text {
        font-size: 3.125vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .text {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc check the "Known issues" tab.

You can also try using js, check this link https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Comment: Did you miss this? _Note: I'm not looking for a simple media query solution where I simply increase the font size @1024px. I'm looking for a way to linearly scale it smoothly between all resolutions._

Comment: Well you have to use media query otherwise you will have font-size at 70px or more at larger resolution. This will scale with lineary scale between breakpoint, that just set the starting point, end and mid way point so the font-size don't scale to much. Well not really linear but that will be readable at least.